# How to insert values from boost::filesystem::directory_iterator() to a map

Tags: c++, iterator, directory, boost-filesystem

```
std::copy(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(paths), 
boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(), // directory_iterator::value_type
std::ostream_iterator<boost::filesystem::directory_entry>(std::cout, "\n"));"
```

The above code will return files in a directory. I need to add those file names into a map.

paths --->boost::filesystem::path

Comment: you mean a set, surely?

Comment: A map? What would be the `key` and the `value`?

Comment: key int value string

Comment: what's the int?

Comment: int means integer

Comment: Would `42` be an acceptable `int`?

Comment: i didnt get you

Comment: actually i need a map contain keys in integer like 1,2,3,...order and values like filename1,filename2 etc

Comment: someone close this question. end the pain. Dilu, you need to tell us exactly what you want. we have no idea what values should go in the keys of the map. We could assume you want ascending integers, like a position. But then we'd be thinking about copying the paths to a vector, not a map.

Comment: yes ascending integer order. its ok if it possible to copy the paths to a vector show me the code..thanks